# Remove every occurance of 'Chapter X' in string in python

Tags: python, replace

I'm looking to remove every occurrence of 'Chapter X', with X being {1,2,3...}. My thoughts were to use an f string, but this only removes the 'Chapter', not the number. Any help of how to remove the number as well? I need to do this without using regular expressions.

```
    for i in text:
        text = text.replace(f'Chapter {i}',"")
```

Comment: If `i` is supposed to be running through the numbers 1,2,3 etc., why do you have `for i in text`?

Comment: Why without regular expressions?

Comment: I'm new to python and thought if I used curly brackets in the f string it would iterate over each number after 'Chapter'.

Comment: If you look up how to loop through a range of numbers in Python, you will be closer.

Comment: Do you know the total number of chapters?

Comment: I do. I tried `for i in range(1,61): text = text.replace(f'Chapter {i}',"")`, This got rid of the Chapter and replaced the numbers 60 and 61 with 0 and 1. Does my code only account for the first digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the number of chapters you can use your technique. Just note that your snippet of code has an error: `for i in text` iterates on a string and `i` is a character, not a number.

```python
for i in range(number_of_chapters)[::-1]:
    text = text.replace(f'Chapter {i + 1}', "")
```

Why does this work? First of all you need to understand how `range` works.

- `range(end)`: `range(10)` will return the "list" [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
- `range(start, end)`: `range(2, 10)` will return the "list" [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
- `range(start, end, increment)`: `range(2, 10, 3)` will return the "list" [2, 5, 8]

The `start` is included, the `end` is excluded.The default `start` is 0 and the default `incremenet` is 1.

I'm using the first version and it goes from 0 to `number_of_chapters` - 1. As you probably have your chapters starting from 1 to `number_of_chapters`, then you add + 1 to `i`.

`[::-1]`: it reverses the "list", so you will start from the end (chapter 61) to the beginning (chapter 1). This prevents issues like replacing "Chapter 60" to "0" because you have replaced "Chapter 6".

Comment: This is yielding me the same issue as the above solution. In the spyder console, 'Chapter 60' and 'Chapter 61' became '0' and '1'.

Comment: `[::-1]` should fix your problem

Comment: See the edited answer and tell me if this fixes your issue

Comment: That's really cool and thanks for the great explanations! It worked!

Comment: Thank YOU for the patience! If you are happy with the answer, could you mark it as solved and upvote?

Comment: You can generate a decreasing range by passing a negative step. You don't need to generate a range with a positive step and then reverse it.